# NullPointerException in AsyncTask where value is checked

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I am developing app in Google play.
My app have "Google Analytics" and I see in Exceptions:

NullPointerException (@AsyncDownload:onPostExecute:70)

Where is the problem ?

```
public class AsyncDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Feed > {

private FragmentCallback mFragmentCallback;

public AsyncDownload(FragmentCallback fragmentCallback) {
    mFragmentCallback = fragmentCallback;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) { 
    Feed feed = ArticlesManager.getInstance().getFeed(arg0[0]);

    if(feed==null){
        try {
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(Ipsum.Headlines[Integer.valueOf(arg0[0])][2]);

                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 3000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

                HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);
                if (rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    String res = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity(),HTTP.UTF_8);

                    Feed feed = RssReader.read(res,Integer.valueOf(arg0[0]) == 7);
                    ArticlesManager.getInstance().addFeed(arg0[0], feed);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    
    }

    return null;
}


protected void onPostExecute(final Feed feed){
    if(mFragmentCallback != null) {
        mFragmentCallback.onTaskDone(feed);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: post entire stacktrace

Comment: as well as any surrounding code (ie, if the AsyncTask is within another class, provide that class)

Comment: @Unmerciful please post the full code related to problem then, it help us to understand the root cause, **FYI** just check whether you initialized the **feed** variable before onPost method get called.

Comment: I don't have stacktrace.

Comment: I think you have to check feed==null..it may be feed!=null..may be i m wrong but i m just guessing.

Comment: @Born To Win i check it onTaskDone

Comment: We need to see the logcat stacktrace..

Comment: @Unmerciful Are you sure feed!=null?

Comment: If you have a NPE thrown, you have a stacktrace. Open the Logcat view to see it. Most probably the original error is not on the onPostExecute#70, but somewhere deeper. Post your onTaskDone method too.

Comment: Also, since this is an AsyncTask, it's recommended to use its advantages, and return the feed from doInBackground, thus you'll have it in your onPostExecute as the input parameter (not Void, you need to change that too). Because the loading is done on a different thread that the feed was declared, thus may be an issue too.

Comment: @deb_rider I have never seen this error. This is error from Google Analytics

Comment: @rekaszeru update onPostExecute to correct return

Comment: You must use a GA call in your onTaskDone (or deeper) method that throws the NPE. Share your relevant snippets along with the stacktrace, please. It's getting hard to pull every single bit of useful information from you by adding separate comments.

Answer (score 0):

please update you **onPostExecute** method this way and test again

```
protected void onPostExecute(final Feed feed)
{
    if(mFragmentCallback != null && feed != null) 
    {
        mFragmentCallback.onTaskDone(feed);
    }
    else
    {
       //the value is null
    }
}
```